# Incorporating CSS into HTML for my Python Script

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, outlook

I am fairly new to the world of coding and python and i am working on an automation which would trigger automatic emails via outlook
The code is use is as follows

```
import win32com.client as win32
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))


outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'user@email.com'
mail.Subject = 'Insert Subject'
table1=df.to_html()
mail.HTMLBody = """
<html>
  <head></head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="df_style.css"/>
  <body>
    <h4>Table 1: Table data<h4>
""" + table1 + """
  </body>
</html>
"""
mail.Send()
```

Ive saved my CSS on the desktop as **df_style** which is as follows

```
.mystyle {
    font-size: 11pt; 
    font-family: Arial;
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    border: 1px solid silver;

}

.mystyle td, th {
    padding: 5px;
}

.mystyle tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #E0E0E0;
}

.mystyle tr:hover {
    background: silver;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

But the changes to the table is not happening and i am left with the plain old table. 
I am not really sure whats going wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two approaches:

1. make sure the path to your css file is set correctly, you may need to use something like:

css_file_path = str(os.path.dirname(**file**) + '/' + 'df_style.css')

and then:

```
mail.HTMLBody = f"""
<html>
  <head></head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={css_file_path}"/>
  <body>
    <h4>Table 1: Table data<h4>
""" + table1 + """
  </body>
</html>
"""
```

2.use style tag in head section:

```
f"""
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {{
                background-color: #ffffff;
            }}
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
....
</body>
</html>
```

Note: if you are using f string, remember to use {{ instead of one for your styles.